# Different definitions of the distribution function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am reading the book *Measure and Integration: An introduction to Real Analysis* by Richard L.Wheeden, Antoni Zygmund, second edition. In chapter 5, the authors give a definition of a distribution function (p. 97):

> It turns out that there is a remarkably simple and useful representation of Lebesgue integrals over subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ in terms of Riemann-Stieltjes Integrals (over susbets of $\mathbb{R}$ , of course) . In order to establish this relation, we must first study the function
> $$\omega (\alpha)=\omega_{f,E} (\alpha)=|\{x \in E : f(x) > \alpha \}|$$
> (here $|\cdot|$ means Lebesgue measure)
> where $f$ is a measureable function on $E$ and $-\infty < \alpha < \infty$. We call $\omega_{f,E}(\alpha)$ the distribution function of $f$ on $E$.

Nevertheless in *Classical Fourier Analysis*, third edition, chapter 1, p.3, Loukas Grafakos gives another definition of a distribution function:

> For $f$ a measureable function on $X$ , the distribution function of $f$ is the function $d_f$ defined on $[0,\infty)$ as follows:

$$d_f (\alpha) = \mu( \{ x \in X : |f(x)| > \alpha \} ) $$

The distribution function $d_f$ provides information about the size of $f$ but not about the behaviour of $f$ itself near any given point. For instance, a function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and each of its translate have the same distribution function.

**( editted )My questions**

1. Kurt G pointed out that they are not the same, Is there some kind of relationship between them? Is there a relation that which implies which?
2. What difference do they both have?

Comment: What does $|\{x \in E : f(x) > \alpha \}|$ mean? Typically the vertical bars denote cardinality but that's clearly not the case here.

Comment: thanks for the reminder, i now go and edit it

Comment: It is pretty obvious that these two definitions are not the same. Those authors are free to give names to the definitions they need however they want, just like you may baptize your child with the same name as I could do with my child. That's it.